# taged person gets new role

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const ALIVE_ROLE = 'Role ID'
const DEAD_ROLE = 'Role ID'

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }
    mention = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (msg.startsWith("Give new role")) {
        if (mention == null) {
            return;
        }
        message.delete();
        mentionMessage = message.content.slice
        mention.member.roles.remove(Role 1);//code fails
        mention.member.roles.add(Role 2);//code fails
        mention.send('you now have a new role');
        message.channel.send("now done");
    }

    });

    client.login('token')
```

I am making a bot that when you send a message that the person @'ed roles get changed but the part noted about that fails any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `message.mentions.members.first()` instead of `message.mentions.users.first()`. A `User` does not have roles whereas a `Member` (a `User` in a `Guild`) does.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const ALIVE_ROLE = 'Role ID'
const DEAD_ROLE = 'Role ID'

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();

    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
    }
    mention = message.mentions.members.first();

    if (msg.startsWith("Give new role")) {
        if (mention == null) {
            return;
        }
        message.delete();
        mentionMessage = message.content.slice
        mention.member.roles.remove(ALIVE_ROLE);//code fails
        mention.member.roles.add(DEAD_ROLE);//code fails
        mention.send('you now have a new role');
        message.channel.send("now done");
    }

    });

    client.login('token')
```